# Auto login after wordpress installation

Tags: customization, installation

I am creating a product in wordpress and here i am installing the custom theme and plugins during wp installation.

No problem until here. But the admin wants to login automatically during the installation ends without prompting for log in and want to redirect to the page what i wish to give.

Any help?

I tried to put this code after the wp_install() in wp-admin/install.php

```
        $creds = array();

        $creds['user_login'] = $_POST['user_name'];

        $creds['user_password'] = $_POST['admin_password'];

        $creds['remember'] = true;          

        $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );

        if ( is_wp_error($user) )
            echo $user->get_error_message();                
        wp_redirect(home_url('products'));exit;
```

Comment: i have updated the code i tried to login

Comment: Don't tell me that you edited a core file...

Comment: i just included the file that i created in wp-content/install.php in upgrade.php

Comment: That ***is*** editing a core file.

Comment: Btw, +1 - I like the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be that you hook in too early (aside from the problem that you're editing a core file), so let's take a look at `wp-admin/install.php`:

No hooks at all, but at the end of the page when everything was properly rendered, there's a call for `wp_print_scripts( 'user-profile' )`. And gladly there we'll find a number of hooks. One that directly sits inside that function on top of it and is named after the function itself: `wp_print_scripts`. And other inside `WP_Scripts`.

So let's give this a try (untested) with a small custom plugin:

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or exit;
/* Plugin Name: (#129229) Auto-Login User after install */

add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wpse129229LoginAfterInstall' );
function wpse129229LoginAfterInstall()
{         
    $user = wp_signon( array(
        'remember'      => true,
        'user_login'    => $_POST['user_name'],
        'user_password' => $_POST['admin_password'],
    ), false );

    if ( is_wp_error( $user ) )
        echo $user->get_error_message();                

    exit( wp_redirect( home_url( "products" ) ) );
}
```

I'm not sure if `admin_password` is the proper `form` field `id`/`name`. Normally/IIRC WP uses `user_password`. Second, the user won't get logged in with `home_url( "products" )`. You'll need to use `admin_url()` for that.

Last Note: ***NEVER EVER*** edit a core file. You'll loose all the changes during any upgrade. If it would be just about installing (and not upgrading) your way of doing it would somehow even be valid (if you want to maintain a WP fork), but not if you want to upgrade.

Comment: thanks for your time. but the code doesnt work and got exit after wp installed.

Comment: First, this is _example_ code. As stated I'm not sure if the `$_POST` data is correct (until you can link to WP core and confirm that). Second, you always need to `exit()` after a `wp_redirect()`. Third, please specify what "got exit" exactly means in your case.

Answer (score 0):

First, instead of editing the core file, notice the following:

1. The `wp-admin/install.php` includes the `wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php` file, right at the top.
2. That upgrade.php file checks for the custom `wp-content/install.php` file and includes it if there. So, your custom install.php file gets included in the install process. This is important because,
3. The `wp_install()` function is wrapped in an `if ( !function_exists() )` type of check. Meaning that the `wp_install()` function itself is "pluggable".

In other words, if you define your own `wp_install()` function in the `wp-content/install.php`, then yours gets used instead, letting you customize the whole function all you like, without editing core.

So, step 1: Copy the existing `wp_install()` function, as is, into your `wp-content/install.php` file. You will modify this function instead of editing the core code.

As for step two, you want to auto-log the resulting user in and redirect. Fortunately, all you really have to do is to set a cookie and then redirect and exit. Easily done. Instead of the `return array` bit at the end of the function, do something more like this:

```
wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id, true);
wp_safe_redirect(home_url('products'));
exit;
```

Note: Untested. Haven't tried it yet. But it should work. You may need to add error handling and such as well.